# What's the difference between sending :include to class and directly defining method in second class definition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, mixins, redmine-plugins

Recently I had to add a method to Redmine's core class. I was unable to use inheritance, so I've done something like this:

```
require_dependency 'time_entry_query'
class TimeEntryQuery < Query
    def my_new_method(foo, bar)
    end
end
```

and it works perfectly - my method is added to all new objects. However, I've seen someone declaring the new method in their own module instead and then sending :include to class, so it become a mixin. Here's an example:

```
module Patches
  module SomeClassPatch
    def my_new_method
    end
end
```

and somewhere in app's initialization:

```
SomeClass.send(:include, Patches::SomeClassPatch) unless SomeClass.include? (Patches::SomeClassPatch)
```

What's difference between these two methods and which one should I use?

Comment: second one is an example of Ruby dynamic programming behavior..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two differences:

1. When you use a mixin, there is a clear place where your "patch" methods can live. If I wonder "Hmm, where's this `my_new_method`" coming from, and I look at, say, `TimeEntryQuery.ancestors` or `TimeEntryQuery.instance_method(:my_new_method).owner`, that will return `Patches::SomeClassPatch`. So I know I have to look for a file named `lib/patches/some_class_patch.rb` somewhere to find where it is probably defined. (I could try `source_location` as well, but that is not always reliable.)
2. Mixing in a module into a class makes the module the superclass of the class it is being mixed into. So, if there already is a `my_new_method` defined in `TimeEntryQuery`, your first option will overwrite it, whereas in your second option, your method will become the `super` method of that method. IOW: with your second option, your new method won't be called unless the already existing method calls `super`.